# Swift core data FetchRequest NSData to UIIMage

Tags: swift, core-data, uiimage

Good morning all, I am using Swift "new for me" and core data I am trying to fetch my stored UIIMage from core data the following way. FYI it is saved as Binary Data in core. And I can see the data if I NSLog it. My Fetch Request looks like this. I have NO ERRORS but my image is not showing.

**When I save to Core Data the NSLog looks like this..**

Did I get to Save Image
2015-10-12 09:05:43.307 Car-Doc-Safe-Plus[13972:3524049] The  NewImage has this in it  (entity: Documents; id: 0x7fd4c0432060  ; data: {
    autoClub = nil;
    **driverLicense = <89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 00000215 00000155 08020000 00d7368a d8000000 01735247 4200aece 1ce90000 001c>;**
    insuranceID = nil;
    noteText = nil;
    plate = nil;
    registration = nil;
})

**But when i Fetch it looks like this..**

The Request has this in it  (entity: Documents; predicate: ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )

```
 **override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Documents")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
let results : NSArray
try! results = context.executeFetchRequest(request)
if results.count > 0 {
    let res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
    carImageView.image = res.valueForKey("driverLicense")as? UIImage

        }
}**
```

**I know I am missing something but I cannot figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
JZ**

Answer (score 0):

The "binary data" type in Core Data is intended for reading and writing `NSData` objects. Since you want to read/write `UIImage`, you need to use the "transformable" type. With transformable, Core Data will attempt to use `NSCoding` to encode/decode the data, converting it to/from `NSData` as needed (Swift `as?` will not do this). Since `UIImage` conforms to `NSCoding`, you don't need to do any extra work except to tell Core Data to convert the data.

Comment: Much appreciated , but how do I use transformable ?

Comment: You set the data type of the attribute to "transformable" in the Core Data model editor. It's the same place where you previously set it to "binary". There's a pop-up list with numeric types, strings, etc, which includes "transformable".

Comment: Great , I see it !! thanks so much. Not many people helped with this , I guess they do not know.  Regards JZ